# Different dates on passport and birth certificate, which one should I use for the DV lottery?

Tags: usa, immigration

The birth dates written on my passport and birth certificate do not match. The actual date is written on the birth certificate, but on the passport, 1/1 is written instead of the actual month and day (this is always the case with passports in my country, for simplification). Which one should I type in the US DV lottery online entry form?

Comment: It’s best to write the accurate date.